# What do the words "coarse" and "fine" mean in the context of computer vision?

Tags: convolutional-neural-networks, computer-vision, terminology, image-segmentation, fully-convolutional-networks

I was reading the well know paper [Fully Convolutional Networks for Semantic Segmentation](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1411.4038.pdf), and, throughout the whole paper, they talk use the term **fine** and **coarse**. I was wondering what they mean. The first time they say it in the intro is:

> Convolutional networks are driving advances in recognition. Convnets are not only improving for whole-image classification, but also making progress on local tasks with structured output. These include advances in
>   bounding box object detection, part and keypoint prediction, and local correspondence.
>
> The natural next step in the progression from **coarse** to **fine** inference is to make a prediction at every pixel.

It's also used in other parts of the paper

> We next explain how to convert classification nets into fully convolutional nets that produce **coarse** output maps.

*What do "coarse" and "fine" mean in the context of this paper? And in the general context of computer vision?*

In English, "coarse" means "rough or loose in texture or grain" , while "fine" means "involving great attention to detail" or "(chiefly of wood) having a fine or delicate arrangement of fibers", but these definitions do not elucidate the meaning of these words in the context of computer vision.

This question was also asked [here](https://qr.ae/pNKKea).

Answer (score 6):

#### tl;dr

> What does that mean in the context of this paper?

With "coarse segmentation" the author means a segmentation that doesn't have much detail. "Fine segmentation", on the other hand, refers to a segmentation with a high level of detail.

> But also more importantly *[what does that mean in the context of]* general computer vision?

The most common use in CV is to describe how general or specific a class in is classification. A "coarse class" is a very broad one, while a "fine class" is a very specific one.

#### Intended use

What the author refers to is the **level of detail** of the resulting segmentation.

A **coarse** segmentation would mean that we have large blobs covering each class without much detail. On the other hand, a **fine** segmentation would have a much higher level of detail which can even go down to pixel level (i.e. pixel-by-pixel correct segmentation).

To make this clear look at the following two examples. As we go from the left to right, the segmentation maps go from coarse to fine:

[image]
[image]

Note that in the rightmost images the result an almost pixel-perfect (i.e. fine details) segmentation map, while the ones on the left don't have much detail and can be considered coarse.

#### Alternative use

Because this isn't an established terminology, some of the times coarse and fine can refer to the nature of the classes in a classification task. Take the top image for example; the label for a coarse classification task could be a *tree*. For a fine classification task we would have labels like *oak tree*, *pine tree*, etc.

The most prominent example of this is the [cifar](https://www.cs.toronto.edu/~kriz/cifar.html) dataset which has two versions: a coarse one that has 10 classes and a fine one that has 100 classes, which are all subclasses of the coarse classes. For example a coarse class is *fish*, while the fine ones are *aquarium fish*, *flatfish*, *ray*, *shark*, *trout*, etc.

For semantic segmentation an example could be the following: you want to make a street segmentation model. This a coarse segmentation would mean that it just splits the image into *road*, *vehicle*, etc. A fine segmentation, on the other hand, could also detect the type of vehicle, e.g. *truck*, *car*, etc.